# Can getResourceAsStream() find files outside the jar file?

Tags: java, resources, jar

I'm developing an application that uses a library that loads a configuration file as:

```
InputStream in = getClass().getResourceAsStream(resource);
```

My application in then packed in a `.jar` file. If `resource` is inside the `.jar` file, I can specify the path as `"/relative/path/to/resource/resource"`.

I'd like to know if is it possible to find the resource if it is outside the `.jar` file, and in this case, how would I specify the path.

(Assuming my application's jar is in `app/` and the resource is in `app/config`).

---

The program uses a 3<sup>rd</sup> party library.
The library uses the resource as a configuration file.

I also want to tweak the configuration file without having to unzip/zip the jar file all the time.

Comment: @AndrewThompson The library uses the resource as a configuration file (it's a thrid party library). I also want to tweak the configuration file without having to unzip/zip the jar file all the time. Actually I forgot to ask if I could accomplish this another way :)

Comment: That information is relevant, so I've edited it into the question.  Can the 3rd party API be instructed (e.g. by your app.) as to where to look for the resource?  Basically what I'm leading to is suggesting not putting it with the app. at all, but in a stable and reproducible path - such as a sub-directory of `user.home`.

Comment: I only just noticed the bit that says 'applet'.  Is this actually an applet?  That further complicates things.

Comment: @AndrewThompson No, it's not an applet. It'a a regular java application.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general, yes it can. Technically, the class's `ClassLoader` is used to locate the resource named in the parameter ([see Javadoc here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29)). If you're not using a special `ClassLoader` then you'll get the bootstrap class loader, which searches the class path. So, if you have directories or other jar files on the classpath, they will be searched.

Answer (score 1):

It will get any resource which is available to the appropriate classloader (the one that `getClass().getClassLoader()` would return). Whether the classloader includes both the `app` directory *and* the jar files depends on the rest of your application context.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to get the current directory ( [How to get the path of a running JAR file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file)), but for configuration you can just pass a `-Dconfig.location` to the JVM specifying an absolute path for the configuration